# How to check whether code is executed on server or client side in GWT?

Tags: java, gwt

I've got one class which is used in both server and client side.
How can I do checking in its constructor that it has been called either from client or server class?

I've done it in dirty way - just try if GWT.create() method throws an exception an if it does, run server side code. But how can I avoid this?

```
    public PrintManager() {
    try {
        factory = GWT.create(MapConfigFactory.class);   //clientsiede factory creation
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        factory = AutoBeanFactorySource.create(MapConfigFactory.class); //serverside factory creator
    }
}
```

Comment: If the behaviour of your class relies on the type of the caller, then you probably should split up the class into two.

Comment: @Oliver Weiler: I did as you wrote, now I have PrintManagerClient and PrintManagerServer classes. Thanks for suggestion

Comment: What if you want it to be transparent? Would you create LogClient.log() and LogServer.log()?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT.isScript()` returns `true` when the code is running as JavaScript on the client.

`com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT.isClient()` returns `false` when the code is running on the server JVM (shared code).

Comment: when running in the eclipse embedded mode, GWT 2.5 was always returning false for GWT.isScript(), i.e. regardless of [server|client] side code

Answer (score 2):

`AutoBeanFactorySource` is not *shared* code, so you cannot use this code on the client. in this case, you need to either:

- use dependency-injection, so that the instance of MapConfigFactory can be provided differently on client-side and server-side
- use `super-source` to have two files for the same class: one for the client-side, and another one for the server-side. `super-source` is explained in the *Overriding one package implementation with another* section of http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects.html#DevGuideModuleXml, it is used by GWT for the Java runtime emulation and, for instance, for the `com.google.gwt.regexp` and `com.google.gwt.safehtml` packages, to provide a unified API that can run in both client and server side.

Comment: AutoBeanFactorySource isn't of course for use in client code, so why can't I just do `if (!GWT.isClient())  factory = AutoBeanFactorySource.create` ... etc ?

Comment: Because every code in the client-side has to be translatable to JS, even if later pruned by the compiler optimizations.